# Unable to install ps3joy driver for ROS

Tags: ros, joystick

I'm trying to install ps3joy driver and I have executed the following command:

```
rosdep install ps3joy
```

Then I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource ps3joy
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/mrad/catkin_ws_top/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

Any solutions please?

Comment: formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are experiencing issues with the installation using rosedep try to do it with ros install instead to see if that works:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-ROSDISTRO-joystick-drivers
```

where ROSDISTRO is the name of your distribution. Let me know if that works. 
[Source](http://wiki.ros.org/ps3joy)